# Merge row data from two 2d arrays on shared column values with different keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, mapping, array-merge

I two arrays set out like this.

First array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [manufacture] => Moto
            [name] => ZSX 125
            [code] => ZS125-48A
            [cc] => 125
            [bike_type] => 3 Motorcycle
            [title] => Mto ZSX 125 
            [about] => The ZSX 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [manufacture] => Moto
            [name] => LSM 125
            [code] => STR125YB
            [cc] => 125
            [bike_type] => 6 Endurancemotor
            [title] => Moto 
            [about] => Moto 
        )
)
```

Second array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 183
            [model] => ZS125-48A
            [engine_brand] => 158FMI-B
            [engine_type] => Single Cylinder
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 172
            [model] => STR125YB
            [engine_brand] => K154FMI
            [engine_type] => Single Cylinder
        )
)
```

As you can see 'code' from the first array is the same as 'model' from the second and there will always be a match.

This is the array i would like to have.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 183
            [model] => ZS125-48A
            [engine_brand] => 158FMI-B
            [engine_type] => Single Cylinder
            [manufacture] => Moto
            [name] => ZSX 125
            [code] => ZS125-48A
            [cc] => 125
            [bike_type] => 3 Motorcycle
            [title] => Moto ZSX 125 
            [about] => The ZSX 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 172
            [model] => STR125YB
            [engine_brand] => K154FMI
            [engine_type] => Single Cylinder
            [manufacture] => Moto
            [name] => LSM 125
            [code] => STR125YB
            [cc] => 125
            [bike_type] => 6 Endurancemotor
            [title] => Moto 
            [about] => Moto 
        )
)
```

Is this possible? i have tried array_merge and array_merge_recursive, but it only appends the second array onto the end of the first, it doesnt merge it on the keys.

Comment: It seems to me like something extracted from DB. If it is, wouldn't be easier to JOIN the results on column `model`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deceze's solution is perfect if the two arrays are synchronized (i.e. items with matching `code` and `model` are at the same index in both arrays). If that is not the case you will need more than one line of code.

The arrays need to have string keys in order to be merged with `array_merge`. In this case you want to rekey the first one based on `code` and the second based on `model`. After rekeying you can merge them with `array_merge_recursive`.

Rekeying is easy in PHP 5.5+:

```
// array_column will conveniently rekey when the second argument is null
$array1 = array_column($array1, null, 'code');
$array2 = array_column($array2, null, 'model');
```

A bit more complicated in earlier versions:

```
// array_map is a more complicated way to extract a column from an array
// and array_combine will do the rekeying
$array1 = array_combine(
              array_map(function($i) { return $i['code']; }, $array1),
              $array1);
$array2 = array_combine(
              array_map(function($i) { return $i['model']; }, $array2),
              $array2);
```

In both cases the final step would be the same:

```
$result = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation and solution :) I think the arrays are sync'd, they seems to me like extracts from DB, which make me think the OP can join the results on `MODEL=>CODE` directly while selecting, but it's just a wild guess :)

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me like this should do it:

```
$array3 = array_map('array_merge', $array1, $array2);
```

This feeds `$array1[0]` and `$array2[0]` to `array_merge`, then `$array1[1]` and `$array2[1]` etc.

Comment: It's ok, but to meet the full requirements of the OP, it should be `$array3 = array_map('array_merge', $array2, $array1);` so the array2 with ID keys will be prepended. +1 from me

Comment: This snippet is correct by happenstance.  If the rows were declared in a different order, the required logic of mapping of `code` values to `model` values would not be upheld.  This is the correct answer to a different question.

Answer (score 1):

And, if you prefer "simpler" code... :-)

```
$result = array();
foreach ($one as $a) {
    foreach ($two as $b) {
        if ($a->code == $b->model) {
           array_push($result, array_merge($a, $b));
           break;
        }
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: This unexplained "simpler" snippet is using bruteforce value comparisons.  Although it does include a conditional `break`, it probably won't perform as fast as a script that makes key-based comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

You can enjoy better efficiency in processing this task if you convert the first array (which will eventually have its row data appended the related row in the second array) to a lookup array.  By leaving the first array's row data unchanged and assigning `code` values as first level keys, you will be able to make instant matches while iterating the second array.

The `+` in the `array_map()` function body is the "union operator" which is a convenient way of merging associative arrays.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aOqGC))

```
$lookup = array_column($array1, null, 'code');
var_export(
    array_map(fn($row) => $row + $lookup[$row['model']], $array2)
);
```

---

For different scenarios where the sought key might not be found in the lookup array, fallback to "uniting" an empty array while mapping.

```
array_map(fn($row) => $row + ($lookup[$row['model']] ?? []), $array2)
```

---

If a lookup array cannot be entertained, then you can merge and push data into a temporarily keyed result array, then remove the temporary keys after relating the data.  [Merge row data based on the column value of two 2d arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72330890/2943403)