# How to combine or merge array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Could this be possible? How to combine or merge arrays in php. to fetch data individualy for echoing purpose. Could this be possible? How to combine or merge arrays in php. to fetch data individualy for echoing purpose.

```
Array(

[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [icd] => J96.0
        [rank] => 1
        [description] => Acute respiratory failure
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [icd] => J44.1
        [rank] => 2
        [description] => Chronic obstructive pulmonary disease with (acute) exacerbation
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [icd] => J18.9
        [rank] => 3
        [description] => Pneumonia, unspecified organism
    )
```

)

To this

```
Array(
 [id]  => 1
 [icd] => (
           [0] => J96.0
           [1] => J44.1
           [2] => J18.9
          )
 [description] => (
                   [0] => Acute respiratory failure
                   [1] => Chronic obstructive pulmonary disease with (acute) exacerbation
                   [2] => Pneumonia, unspecified organism
                  )

)
```

Comment: at least show some effort and attempt

Comment: [This SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112920/array-merge-on-key-of-two-associative-arrays-in-php) has the answer you are looking for.  Please read it and then answer your own question.

Comment: This question doesn't really offer enough clarity.  There are some techniques (in the answers below) that will work on this sample input but not work if there are multiple `id`s.  Please provide a better, more complex [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

USe This

```
array_merge_recursive
```

Follow Link

[Link With Example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = array();

$arrayAB = array_merge($arrayA, $arrayB);
foreach ( $arrayAB as $value ) {
    $keys = array("id", "icd", "rank", "description"); 
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $currKey = $value[$key];
        if ( !isset($output[$currKey]) ) {
            $output[$currKey] = array();
        }
        $output[$currKey] = array_merge($output[$currKey], $value);
    }
}

var_dump($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($your_array as $row){
         $new_array['id']        = $row->id;
         $new_array['icd'][] = $row->icd;
         $new_array['description'][] = $row->description; 
}
print_r($new_array);
```